# Managed and Unmanaged related to remoting handle leak

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, remoting

I have an remote server application.

Clients can connect either managed data access and unmanaged access through a wrapper. Communication between the clients and the server is running through .NET remoting services.

The clients that connect through managed data access does not have handle leaks. But, the clients using the unmanaged wrapper results in a handle leak. I checked the unmanaged wrapper and it seems straight forwarded and it should not cause the handle leaks.

Is this something that is a common issue with .NET framework?

My point asking really is that when isolating our handle leak problem, I found out that when doing the same open and closing .NET remoting connection from client to server (no other stuff like sending and requesting data, just open and closing connection/session), the managed client does not show handle leaks and the unmanaged clients somehow shows handle leak.

Comment: Posting the code you have tried would help to give you an answer. The .NET framework has been around long enough to have found significant errors. With unmanaged code it could be any memory allocation/deallocation or a point gone astray.

Comment: @SteveFerg, will workout a shrunk project to illustrate what I mean.